# Why are there random dates data on intraday tables in Bigquery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have set a Google Analytics to BigQuery daily export for one of our views. According to my knowledge the intraday tables which is populated thrice a day gets deleted once ga_sessions() populates. 
Recently I observed that there are random dates data on the intraday tables. 
Having a look at the logs on stack driver I don't observe any anomaly.

Please could some one explain this case.
[Refer this image!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AErFL.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the missing date in the drop down list exists when you query it?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that missing dates don't exist when I query.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery UI propose you to select only the existing partition. If you haven't data for a giving date, there is no partition, and thus, there is no proposal on the GUI.

Can seem strange, but it's useful!!

Comment: Makes sense but would be interesting to know if intraday tables are retained for a specific duration.